# Selecting two columns from different tables in one result using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

[image]

[image]

Selecting two columns from different tables in one result using MySQL.

how can make it in MySQL and CakePHP

Comment: [JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using and what have you tried so far? As it stands there is not enough information for a proper answer.

Comment: Query in CakePHP : $options = array( 'fields' => array( 'Usercat.user_id',), 'joins' => array( array('conditions' => array('Userarea.area_id' => $area_id,), 'table' => 'user_area', 'alias' => 'Userarea', ), ), 'conditions' => array( 'Usercat.cat_id' => $cat_id, ), 'group' => array( 'user_id', ), 'contain' => array( 'Userarea', ), ); $data = $this->Usercat->find('all', $options); @drmonkeyninja

Comment: @GhalySaqqal in future specify the version of CakePHP you are using. From your last comment I assume it is either CakePHP 1.x or 2.x, but you would write a very different query for CakePHP 3.x. Your question is a bit vague and as a result you haven't been supplied with the best answers, although appear to have solved it yourself. It would perhaps be a good idea to post your own solution and mark it as the answer seeing as it is better than the one you've currently accepted!

Comment: @drmonkeyninja this query in CakePHP 2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL query would be

```
$sql = "SELECT t1.user_id FROM table1 AS t1 
                   JOIN table2 AS t2
                   ON t2.area_id = 3 
                   WHERE t1.cat_id = 11"

$this->query($sql);
```

See [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query) for the documentation

Comment: Please don't write queries like this in CakePHP. This could all be done using CakePHP's ORM which would lead to much safer code.

Comment: and you can make it in CakePHP : 
$options = array(
    'fields' => array( 'Usercat.user_id',),
     'joins' => array(
             array('conditions' => array('Userarea.area_id' => $area_id,),
              'table' => 'user_area',
              'alias' => 'Userarea',
             ),
         ),
         'conditions' => array(
             'Usercat.cat_id' => $cat_id,
         ),
         'group' => array(
               'user_id',
         ),
         'contain' => array(
             'Userarea',
          ),
 );
$data = $this->Usercat->find('all', $options);

Answer (score 0):

You can use INNER JOIN between tables, the query will be:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
```

CakePHP has his owns ORM, you can check it out here:

Simple query.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-rows-from-a-table

Associations:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#loading-associations

Regards.

Comment: SELECT t1 . * , t2 . * 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
WHERE cat_id =2
AND area_id =3

I got empty result when I use it

Comment: Yeah, that is because your user_id does not have a cat_id 2. Try LEFT JOIN ... but i think the problem is not the query. The problem is the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM table1, table2 
WHERE table1.cat_id = 2 and table2.area_id = 3
```

but i am a litle bit confused what you want... :S